# Capture image from video file URL

Tags: image, url, video, take

-(void)captureImageFromUrlPath : (NSString *)urlStr {

```
// Import this from for these classes #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr] options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator* imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) actualTime:nil error:nil]];
UIImageView  *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageView setImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to capture image from video file Url.